# Redirect to URL in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I need some help. I have been working on a way to load a page from within the "program.cs" file created by VS 2017 and ASP.NET Razor, but I cannot work out how this is done. I have looked on the web to find the answer, but I cannot find anything that will work.

What I'm looking to do is, after a lookup, I need to load the page again with an added `searchstring`. I have all the code doing the lookup and cross-checking, but I'm unable to get the code to redirect to the page again with the added `searchstring`.

```
Response.Redirect("/machinery?MachineLocation=" + searchstring);
```

The above code will not work in "program.cs" or "startup.cs," but it will work in any "cshtml.cs" file.

I have tried to DI the `HttpContext`, but this keeps returning `null`.
Any pointers would be great.

Comment: The purpose of `Response.Redirect` is to send the user making the HTTP request to another page. If you're trying to do this in `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`, there *is no user* to redirect, so it doesn't make sense. You should try and describe in more detail exactly what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Add more details why do you want to do it in program.cs or startup.cs, do you use MVC?

Comment: The purpose is the main index page has tabs across the top 'Locations' I have a timer running that I would like to get the 'Locations' tab and then move to the next tab via reloading the page with the Location in the url under searchstring the MVC would then load from the database but would use the location as a search string.

Comment: If your are in a controller you can do `return this.Redirect("myurl")`. There other redirect methods available.

Comment: this.Redirect at first did not work as it was a static class so I had to remove this and create an instance of the timer class this allowed Redirect to run but it is not going to the URL.

Comment: Hi anyone out there that can help with this issue please.

Answer (score 57):

Redirecting from a controller to a full URL is done simply by:

```
return Redirect(stringFullUrl);
```

Comment: For security reasons please also have a look at @Zeyad answer.

Answer (score 28):

Short answer, use:

```
return LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl);
```

Long answer (important for security purposes):

Looks like you are grabbing the url from the user, if that is the case, I do not recommend using `return Redirect(ReturnUrl);` by itself because this opens a channel for Open Redirect Vulnerability Attacks. Basically someone can have an anchor element somewhere (like in an advertisement or so) that directs the user to your login page with a query string parameter that is named ReturnUrl that points to their own malicious website. Another way is that the ReturnUrl query string will redirect the users from your login form to a malicious login form that looks exactly like yours and then they show the user that the password was incorrect, making them think that maybe they missed a letter or so, so the users attempt to login again, but this time they are actually submitting their credentials to the malicious login form not yours. The hacker will then redirect them to your website after submitting their credentials to your website so that they don't notice anything wrong, it will just seem to them that they mis-typed the password but on the second attempt, they logged in successfully.
So using `LocalRedirect()` instead of `Redirect()` will check first if the return url is your own website's url, if not then the redirect fails and an exception is thrown. Another way to avoid the exception yet check for local url is to do the following:

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl)) {
    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
}
```

That will give you the same result without throwing the exception because you are checking first if the url belongs to your web application or not, before proceeding with the redirection