# Redirect URL With Parameter (POST METHOD)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect

I want to call the WEB API `POST Method`, but it will redirect windows to another page without return anything . What can i use ?

I have try to use the `Response.Redirect(URL)` , but it cannot be pass the parameters .And i have try `HttpClient client = new HttpClient()` call like web api post method, but it will not redirect windows to another page .

In JavaScript i have use the 
                    `$.redirect('https://livinggateway.azurewebsites.net/LivingPayment/CardPayment', {'orderId': data.data, 'paymentAmount': parseFloat($('.CardTotalAmount').val()) } , 'POST');`

But in controller i have no idea .

/// Code of controller call api

```
using (HttpClient client= new HttpClient())
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://URL");

var content = BuildContent(new
{
   orderId = secondResponseResult.data,
   paymentAmount = paymentCC.txnAmountWithCharges
});

client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://URL", content).;
}
```

Comment: Not clear to me! Is that API getting called successfully?

Comment: Web API are used for exchanging data.... redirecting to a URL from Web API is not recommended.... If the user is not logged in you should return 401 response from the API.

Comment: Hi @PrashantPimpale, The API is getting successfully . if successfully it should be redirect the windows to another url .

Comment: Then use [Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3514016/7124761)

Comment: I wants to do in controller now .

Comment: Is that MVC Application? Or Web API?

Comment: MVC Application

Comment: Try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308563/redirect-to-url-in-asp-net-core

Comment: with sync API call

Comment: Try this : https://long2know.com/2016/07/capturing-redirects-with-httpclient/

Comment: Do you have two applications , or the web api controller in an mvc application? What do you mean by " redirect the windows to another url " ?