# How to Redirect to Last Visited page After Login in Asp.net core mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag

I had done many solutions for Last Visited page after Login but I am unable to found any solutions. Please help me with this

```
ViewBag.returnUrl = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
```

I had done this & call Viewbag.returnUrl in cshtml page of Login but not working

Answer (score 0):

The redirect should happen in the Controller after the credentials are validated. Instead of returning the login page with the viewbag information, like mentioned here:

[redirect to url in ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308563/redirect-to-url-in-asp-net-core/55383749)

If you're doing this with JS, or you need to land on this page first, for whatever reason, then you can just redirect using javascript:

```js
window.location.replace("myUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.QueryString[]`. Set from master page and get data from login page. If login is confirmed redirect this URL.

Comment: Can you give me proper solution about this that how we can work with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method

```
ViewBag.returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
```